# SwiftUI, Timer: Timer not firing

Tags: timer, swiftui, watchkit

I am using WatchKit and SwiftUI to build an Apple Watch application.
At the start of my struct, I am initialising a publishing  Timer:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var index: Int = 0
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.2, on: .main, in: .default)

var body: some View {
    return AnyView(VStack{
    Image(uiImage: images[index])
         .resizable()
         .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
         .onReceive(timer) { (_) in
            self.index = self.index + 1
            if self.index > images.count - 1 {
               self.index = 0
            }
            debugPrint(self.index)
         }
```

The images: [UIImage]! array is defined globally in another file (for now).
The  first image does  get  displayed immediately.
Now neither the Image updates, nor do I see a debugPrint of self.index.
To me this means that the timer never started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot the add .autoconnect() to line 3:

```
let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.2, on: .main, in: .default).autoconnect()
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting your timer directly inside `onReceive()` should work:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var index: Int = 0

var body: some View {
    return AnyView(VStack{
    Image(uiImage: images[index])
         .resizable()
         .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
         .onReceive(Timer.publish(every: 0.2, on: .main, in: .default)) { (_) in
            self.index = self.index + 1
            if self.index > images.count - 1 {
               self.index = 0
    }
    debugPrint(self.index)
}
```

Comment: Likely because the timer lives in the `body` vs `struct` level. The body get reloaded the timer disappears